# Redis lua script atomicity

Tags: transactions, lua, redis, atomic

Hi I read a lot in the last days about Lua script and Redis, but I'm still not sure about the following (I use a simple example that let you to understand well the meaning of my question):

- I have to execute 3 set commands and if any of them fails I want the redis keys state is restored to the state before the lua script execution (so if the first set succeed and the second fails and so the script failed i want that the key value changed by the first set is restored to the old one).

My application sends command to redis using a connection pool (each of this connection is considered as a different client by redis) and each command uses a different connection of the pool. It seems to me that using MULTI/EXEC is not so easy in such a case so i thought about a Lua script (and send only one Eval command). But i need to be sure of the state restoration if any failures before modifying application source code...

Thanks in advance for all your replies...

Comment: Indeed - since you want to "rollback" (although I'm not sure what you mean by SET failing), a Lua script would be the best way to go about this.

Comment: Instead of trying to describe your problem generically, you are more likely to get a decent answer if you put some specific code that you have attempted, and describe _exactly_ what you want to happen at various points that it isn't currently doing.